# How to split StringBuilder or print side by side

Tags: java, android

i'm developing an App in Android Studio and trying to send a list through email or WhatsApp. It's a list with product and quantity but it has to be side by side like:

```
product1 - quantity1
product2 - quantity2
product3 - quantity3
```

I tried in many ways but i can't get it to work side by side and the closest i got is code that i'm pasting here. it must go all the list at once. How can i do it???

```
 fabShare = findViewById(R.id.fabShare);
    fabShare.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener( ) {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
            intent.setType("text/plain");
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder();

            for (int i = 0; i < listaCompras1.size(); i++){

                String p = listaCompras1.get(i);
                sb.append(p);

                String q = listaCompras2.get(i);
                sb2.append(q);


            }


            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, sb.toString() + "\n" + sb2.toString());

            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "share via"));


        }
    });
```

Comment: this wont work, whatsapp and other apps are going to break the lines the way they want... you didn't inject enough spaces to make over the differents product names length... whatsapp and major app fonts are not shell type, it means different letters have different sizes and it wont ever print the way you put on example

Comment: when making a propper question fill enough information to people help you, nobody will guess what `lisaCompras` is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use html, or you can literally insert new lines.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < listaCompras1.size(); i++){
    sb
      .append(listaCompras1.get(i))
      .append(" - ")
      .append(listaCompras2.get(i))
      .append("\n");
}
```

Rather than storing parallel String lists, though, it would be better if you had a single `List<Compra>`

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following :

```
    StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < listaCompras1.size(); i++){ 
        String p = listaCompras1.get(i);
        String q = listaCompras2.get(i);
        joiner.add(p + " - " + q);
    }
    String result = joiner.toString();
```

A `StringBuilder` could have been used like

```
        sb.append(p).append(" - ").append(q).append("\n");
```

in the loop but would have resulted in an extra newline at the end. The StringJoiner avoids that.

Your existing code is appending the product and quantity values in two different builders. The above statement appends them in one builder placing them side by side.